# React.js and React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I read all of react-native's documents and now I'm reading all of Reacts documents.

So do all of the underlying functions of React in their documents live in and are available in React Native?

With the exception of ReactDOM.render() vs ... well whatever equivalent for React Native is for this and other functions that are platform-specific

For instance, can I rely on the methods in this document?

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html#component-lifecycle

To be the same in React Native?

I'm just having trouble separating what's for what

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use same lefe cycle methods also in react-native. As you've mentioned, only difference between them is view components.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of differences between ReactJS and React Native, one is a library and the other is a framework.

So, You should not use the [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) documentation to create your ReactNative app, ReactNative has it's own [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/).

I suggest you to read this [article](https://medium.com/@alexmngn/from-reactjs-to-react-native-what-are-the-main-differences-between-both-d6e8e88ebf24#.cdoxkkb66) about the differences. =D